# google bigquery excel connector

Tags: excel, google-bigquery

I am trying to load data from bigquery to excel but getting the error
***Unable to open https://bigquery-connector.appspot.come/data. Cannot downloaded the information you requested.***
My query runs fine on BQ console but on excel I am getting that error and then it stops processing. Similar query in other worksheet works fine. I copied my file and modified the query string and now I am getting that error.
It fetches round 24 records ( Hourly for last 24 Hrs ) and processes 5GB data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [ODBC drivers for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/). The ODBC driver is able to support standard or legacy SQL syntax and queries with more rows than the web connector. I suspect your query might be timing out with the web connector.